# Understand some wp theme css code

Tags: css, wordpress

This is an extract from file style.css in WordPress theme Twenty sixteen. I have this part of code which creates a black strip on the top and bottom of the page.

```
body:not(.custom-background-image):before,
body:not(.custom-background-image):after {
    background: inherit;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 21px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

I affirm this cause I've understand that modifying the height to `0px` I let the strips to disappear. But how do these instructions work to create the two strips ?  I know it's also a whole CSS work but I think those instructions make the great part of the job.

The preview of the theme is here :
https://wordpress.org/themes/twentysixteen/.

The whole style.css file is here :
https://github.com/WordPress/twentysixteen/blob/master/style.css#L18-L51

Who can help me to clear things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:before` and `:after` are pseudo selectors. With this you can design what happens before/after the element.

`Background: inherit;` will inherit the background from the body element.

Note that there is also a `margin: 21px` on `.page`

Comment: My point is to understand where do the two strips come from. I know about before and after statement, and I've seen the margin set on .page class. The strips are shown also if I set that margin to 0px. The fog is still there about why those instructions create the two strips.

Comment: Well the strips come from exactly that. The before and after have a height of 21px. And have the dark bg color.

Comment: Why I have two strips and not only one ? Why they are attached to top and bottom of the page in a symmetrical position? I can see a "left : 0" and I suppose this set the strip on the left position but where do the "top :0" position (or symmetrical for bottom) is set ?  I need an answer to this questions ...

Comment: Your body is already against the top. Thus placing content before that will also stick to the top. And vice versa for the after.

Comment: Oh God! That's it. Thank you guy!